# readr::read_file not being able to read the file

Tags: r, readr

I'm using the read::readfile function to make some changes to the XML file by R itself. For some reason, the above function doesn't work on my computer (it returns Error: Invalid multibyte sequence), while it works on a colleague's computer. Could it be an encoding problem or has anyone had the same problem?

```
> library(magrittr)
> "20220218_Pedidos_xml_2020.xml" %>%
+   readr::read_file(locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE")) %>%
+   stringr::str_replace_all("<Pedido ", "\n\t<Pedido ") %>%
+   stringr::str_replace("</Pedidos>", "\n</Pedidos>") %>%
+   stringr::str_remove_all("&#x[0-9A-F]{2};") %>% # Remover caracteres inválidos
+   stringr::str_c('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n', .) %>%
+   readr::write_file("20220218_Pedidos_xml_2020.xml")
Error: Invalid multibyte sequence
```

File: 20220218_Pedidos_xml_2020.xml available in https://dadosabertos-download.cgu.gov.br/FalaBR/Arquivos_FalaBR_Filtrado/Arquivos_xml_2020.zip

PS: the file name changes according to the day it is downloaded, but the content remains the same.

Comment: Most people don't trust downloading random zip archives from strangers on the internet, so this might not help in getting your question answered. This said, have you tried running your script one line at a time without the pipes, to see where the error happens?

Comment: This looks pretty drastic: `str_remove_all("&#x[0-9A-F]{2};)` Have your tried taking one of each of the modifications out ands seeing whether it runs? The encoding might be off so you might try a could of other encodings.

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, the problem is in the first line (readr::read_file(locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE")) ).